# AWS Cloud watch Cronjob expression for monday to friday

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using below cronjob expression in AWS Cloud watch for starting ec2 everyday, 
15 3 * * ? *

can anyone please help me with cronjob expression for monday to friday for scheduling ec2

Answer (score 2):

Simply put `MON-FRI` in the *day of week* field and question mark in the *day of month* field.

```
15 3 ? * MON-FRI *
```

Note that the times are always in UTC. See here for docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

Hope that helps :)